# Call Web Services on post first publish

Tags: posts, hooks, actions, web-services, rest-api

I want to call some web service when i publish a post. I want to add a checkbox so as to decide whether to call or not call after publishing.

I have found the code to call both REST and SOAP web services but i dont know:

1. How to add a checkbox in the "new post" admin page.
2. How to invoke a function that contains web service call code, in "on publish" action
3. How to use the checkbox value to invoke or not invoke the above
   function and
4. How is post title, post category, post excerpt
   represented so as to add the values in my request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To add a checkbox you need to use the [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function, with this you can create a metabox for the new post screen. You have to create a function that generates the checkbox element, and that's it.
2. You can use the action [`publish_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post) to call the services you need when it happens, you have other options, like [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post). It really depends on how flexible you want your code to be.
3. In step one you created a custom metabox, when you wrote that function, you should've created an `input` element with a `name`, so, you can access the value of the checkbox from the POST array, like this `$_POST['name_of_the_field']`.
4. If you use the `publish_post` action, you can get the Post data like this:

   ```
   add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_publish_func', 10, 2 );

   function post_publish_func($id, $post){

   $title = $post->post_title; //or get_the_title()
   $categories = get_the_category($id);
   $checkbox = $_POST['name_of_the_checkbox'];

   //magic goes here
   }
   ```

Be careful using `get_the_title` or `$post->post_title`, because if you are modifying a post, `get_the_title` gets the value already stored in the DB (the title before you made the modifications) and `$post->post_title` gets the value of the modified version. This happends with other methods too, `get_the_content` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger your web-service-calling code by using this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post

You can add a checkbox using this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box